# How to change the substitute fonts selected for unavailable fonts by Powerpoint 2010

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

Apologies if this is the wrong stackexchange to ask in.

I've got several dozen powerpoint files which were generated on a different computer, probably with a different version of PowerPoint (I'm not sure). They were saved in SansSerif, which isn't available under that name. Instead of being substituted for MS Sans Serif, it's being replaced with Wingdings which is annoying to say the least.

Does anyone know how to force it to replace with MS Sans Serif instead? I've tried adding a FontSubstitute for it in the registry. I've tried copying the MS Sans Serif font, using a hex editor to rename it to SansSerif and importing it back in. Neither of these have helped with Powerpoint.

Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to change only the substituted font or do you want to change the presentation to use MS Sans Serif instead of SansSerif?

You can replace fonts wholesale pretty easily using the Replace Fonts dialog box.

If you don't know where to find it, mention what version of PPT you use.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's powerpoint 2010 (although I no longer have the laptop, so I'm only interested out of curiousity now). SansSerif doesn't exist, and behind the scenes PowerPoint was replacing it with wingdings. In Word 2010 there's a way to see the missing fonts, but not in PowerPoint as far as I could see. I wanted the change to apply for the whole of the installation, rather than fixing up each of the dozens of slideshows manually.

Comment: There used to be a registry entry or ini file setting somewhere that let you specify font substitutions; I haven't heard any reference made to it in the last hundred or so years, so I don't know if it exists any longer.  Other than that, I don't know that there's any way to globally make this change; it'd have to be a presentation at a time.

Comment: Ah.  Wait.  Have a look at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Font Mapping

Answer (score 0):

I have analyzed your request and found a possible solution. One alternative approach would be to obtain the actual font itself. After conducting a search, I have located a website that offers the "SansSerif" font. The link is as follows: http://fonts.radio-electronics.co/font/SansSerif/SansSerif%20font.htm. Hope this helps.